# Assign dash.layout function dynamically by flask app.route

Tags: javascript, python, flask, plotly-dash

I am trying to change the function assignment of the dash_app.layout dynamically within a flask app instance.

The Flask app is built by the factory method and most importantly consists out of

1. `app = Add_Dash(app)` --> here the Dash app is initialized with pre-fix /dash-app
2. `app.register_blueprint`(routes.main_bp) --> where the routes are added

within the Add_Dash class, a function is assigned to the dash_app.layout that returns/ instructs to render the html/DOM Graphs at runtime (the assignment is done at initialization/ server start)

```
dash_app.layout = chStatistics
```

The dash application is executing this function (chStatistics) and re-rendering DOM every time a user calls the dash app.

In the 'index.html' (that is rendered by flask template) I have built a navigation that controls the JS call rendering the dash graphs (`$.renderer = new DashRenderer();`). This executes the function assigned to `dash_app.layout`.
So far, this all works fine.

Now, I would like to reassign the `dash_app.layout = newFunction` within `routes.py` module. The final setup would then look like:

1. User clicks navigation button
2. An asynchronous JS XHR request is sent to the flask sever and picked up in the routes.py module
3. In routes.py module the `dash_app.layout = newFunction` is assigned (changed from `dash_app.layout = chStatistics`
4. In the callback of the JS XHR call, the `$.renderer = new DashRenderer();` is executed, rendering the dash app*
5. Dash app now uses the new function to retrieve the graphs

I was thinking that I could create a router function that is initially assigned when dash app comes to live and then executes either the chFunction or the newFunction based on a session variable set by the router.py module. I am, however, not sure if that is the most optimal way of doing it.

*) for completeness purposes I should mention that this is simplified. In reality there is additional DOM manipulation ongoing (e.g. del of #react-entry-point) so that dash re-renders again